# how can I change yoast seo generated sitemap file URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap, yoast, xml-sitemap

I have a wordpress website with yoast seo plugin installed. currently the sitemap url is [www.domain.com/sitemap_index.xml](http://www.domain.com/sitemap_index.xml). As far as I know from my search results on Internet, yoast plugin itself doesn't have such option/feature for changing generated sitemap url, how can I change this url to a customized one programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

```
plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/sitemaps/class-sitemaps-router.php
```

Change line 34 to:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'your_name_here\.xml$', 'index.php?sitemap=1', 'top' );
```

Inside Yoast Dashboard (admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard) click on 'Save Changes'

Comment: I know that plugin can't do it itself.

Comment: @blank94 just edited my question. Give it a try

Comment: the tricky thing here was clicking on save changes, thanks!

Comment: but what will happen when Yoast version will get updates?

Comment: @FrontendDevWebAccessibility Obvious everything will be overridden. Even line 34 could be changed.

Comment: In case you couldn't find the "Save Changes" button which is not at 'admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard', after updating the rewrite rules go to your_home_url/wp-admin/options-permalink.php then click "Save Changes" at the bottom.